# preg_replace change link in href value, but not in src

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

I need to replace urls in the page taken by curl and add correct link. My php curl code is:

```
<?php

$string = '<a href="http://host.org"><img src="./sec.png"></a>';

$string = preg_replace('/href="(http:\/\/([^\/]+)\/)?([^"]+)"/', "href=\"http://google.com/\\3\"", $string);

echo $string;

?>
```

When the link is "a" it cut all link and left only href value.

```
//from
<a href="http://host.org"><img src="./sec.png"></a>

//to BUGgg when href fix make :
<a href="http://google.com/./sec.png"></a>
```

Can any body help in fix it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [preg\_replace change link from href](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19190180/preg-replace-change-link-from-href)

Comment: oh, no there is not duplicate, first one was preg_match to find if there is an http link, i have cutted it, to make question more simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following preg_replace should work:

```
preg_replace('/href="(http:\/\/[^\/"]+\/?)?([^"]*)"/', "href=\"http://google.com/\\2\"", $result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this unnecessary part from your regexps: `([^/]+)/`